# Imacros stops when error occurs from server

Tags: javascript, imacros, browser-automation

I am using imacros chrome extension to automate my work. Imacros opens a link and then fill some values and click on submit button and again loads the link and do the same. Sometimes an error occurs when it clicks on submit button. And the script just stops until i stop the loop and start the loop again. This error occurs in all browsers, i tested chrome, edge, opera, brave, etc.

Here is ther error screen:

[image]

Here is imacros extension while it stops:

[image]

I am also using IGNOREERRORS. It is causing me a problem. When i open my pc after few hours it is stuck and waste all time. Every time it stops it is on line 35.

```html
VERSION BUILD=1011 RECORDER=CR 
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.1
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\iMacros\Macros/mail2.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
'SET !USERAGENT "{{!COL6}}"
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !VAR08 EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 5);")
URL GOTO=My_Link
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Donate<SP>Now
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_Amount CONTENT=${{!VAR08}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_Email CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_FirstName CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_LastName CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_Address CONTENT=address
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_City CONTENT=city
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_PostalCode CONTENT=96080
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=TXT:I<SP>understand<SP>that<SP>gifts<SP>eligible<SP>for<SP>tax-d*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_Agreement CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=TXT:I<SP>understand<SP>MissionMinder<SP>will<SP>deduct<SP>1%*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:GiveForm ATTR=ID:DT_Acknowledgement CONTENT=YES
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.5
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON  ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>»
FRAME F=1
SET !VAR07 EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*15 + 1);")
'WAIT SECONDS ={{!VAR07}}
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 60
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Pay<SP>With<SP>Bank
FRAME F=1
WAIT SECONDS=3
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Continue
WAIT SECONDS =1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=hhhhh
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Exit
WAIT SECONDS =1
FRAME F=0
WAIT SECONDS =1
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:microdeposit-button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-user-name CONTENT={{!COL4}}<SP>{{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-user-email CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:bank-account-wrapper
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-bank-name CONTENT=wells
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-routing-number CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-account-number CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:text-input-confirm-account-number CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Checking
WAIT SECONDS =2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:microdeposit-submit ATTR=ID:confirm-button
WAIT SECONDS =2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:microdeposit-complete ATTR=ID:confirm-button
WAIT SECONDS =1
FRAME F=1
WAIT SECONDS =3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON  ATTR=TXT:Confirm
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK
WAIT SECONDS =1
'FRAME F=0
'TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Click<SP>Here
CLEAR
```

Comment: That appears to be an error on the server end.  It's possible the site is detecting whatever you're doing and is trying to prevent it.

Comment: is there a way to start everything again after this error?

Comment: I don't know iMacros; does TIMEOUT_STEP=0 mean it waits infinitely?  Can't you set the timeout to some value, and catch the timeout?

Comment: TIMEOUT_STEP=0 mean it waits for 0 seconds for that tag and then moves forward

Comment: You should be able to detect when you get that error.  Remember, it's not YOUR error; the web server is delivering that to you as normal HTML.  You can View Source on the error page and find something that you can use to identify it.